# why can i add files to my ipod but not my iphone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod

I have just bought an album and have imported it to my itunes. I can drag the files onto my ipods but not onto my iphone.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Is your iPhone synced with the library you are using? Can you drag any other files onto the iphone?

Comment: I am not sure, I havent really messed with the sync button as I was scared I might get rid of contacts etc. I can't drag anything into the iphone not just music.

Comment: Sounds like your phone is synced with another library, hence why you can't copy to it. It's a part of the block to not be able to just transfer content to other computers and such.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to drag/drop media tracks freely from your iTunes library to your iPhone, you need to set your iTunes sync settings for your iPhone to manual mode.

1. Connect your iPhone to your computer and run iTunes.
2. Select your iPhone, iPad, or iPod. If your device is not visible in the upper right corner of the screen, choose Library first.
3. Click the Summary tab and select "Manually manage music and videos".
4. Make sure that contacts and calendar sync is not enabled from the Info tab
5. Click Apply.

You can now drag/drop songs from your iTunes library to your iPhone